# Differences between the size of the output area when using Polygon's symmetricDifference method versus the Symmetrical Difference tool in ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, polygon, arcgis-pro, symmetric-difference, symdifference

I have two overlapping polygons to compare (using ArcGIS Pro 3.0) originated from a DWG file. One as a polygon (closed polyline in AutoCAD). The second as a 3D solid converted to polygon using [Multipatch Footprint](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/3d-analyst/multipatch-footprint.htm) tool. Ideally, both should have the same XY vertices but differences are expected between the two objects. I'm getting a different output polygon area when using symmetricDifference method of the [Polygon Class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/polygon.htm) versus [Symmetrical Difference](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/symmetrical-difference.htm) tool and having trouble to decide which way is better (Polygon Class method is preferred for runtime reasons).

Geoprocessing tool:

[image]

Method:

[image]

Spatial reference is the same for both:
[image]

Any idea what causes this difference?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: There may be differences in how the SpatialReference is defined that changes vertex locations. It's impossible to tell with the limited data provided.

Comment: If you look at the very help page you link to it states - _Coordinates may move within the resolution of the geometry's spatial reference._

Comment: it would be great if you could share vertices coordinates list for both geometries (if it is not too long) and coordinate systems . Judging by the shape of diffs it might be related to rounding effects.

Comment: @Vince The two objects originated from a DWG file. One as a polygon (closed polyline in AutoCAD). The second as a 3D solid converted to polygon using "Multipatch Footprint" tool. Ideally, both should have the same XY vertices but differences are expected. Spatial reference is the same for both Feature classes and both geometries.

Comment: @Szym One of the polygons created using the "Multipatch Footprint" tool therefore has many more vertices than the other polygon. I also tried changing the env.maintainCurveSegments setting but there was no significant difference.

Comment: So, yeah, there's going to be a number of differences between the conversion paths, so many that it's almost not worth counting. SpatialReference is much more than just coordinate reference, and that's where your difference lies.

Comment: @Vince The differences between the two polygons are not a big deal to me. As I mentioned, that is expected. My problem is which method to use to evaluate the difference - native tool or class method.

Comment: If the source is CAD, you really want ArcObjects, not Python, so the native tool is likely to work better out of the box.